# How to pass an Objective-C with callback to a Swift method?

Tags: ios, swift

I really don't know how to ask this question, but:

1. I have a bridge between Objective-C and Swift
2. In my Obj-C class I invoke my Swift class

```
IAPbridge = [[IAPBridge alloc] init];
[IAPbridge requestProducts];
```

3. I have a swift class

```
public func requestProducts ()  {

}
```

4. My Obj-C class should have a block to receive some data from the Swift class
5. It should be something like this (this code is wrong, but something like what I think it should be)

Obj-C

```
[IAPbridge requestProducts:^(id *products) {
    NSLog(@"Response:%@", products);
}];
```

Swift

```
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ products: [SKProduct]?) -> Void
private var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?    

public func requestProducts (completionHandler)  {
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
}
```

So, any help?

Comment: You seem to know the answer already, so can you explain what problem actually remains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is impossible as your spec stands:

```
productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
```

You cannot hand back *two* values if a ProductsRequestCompletionHandler takes only *one* value. So you will have to revise your definition of a ProductsRequestCompletionHandler.

We may then imagine that on the Swift side we have a class like this:

```
@objc class IAPBridge : NSObject {
    public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (Bool, [SKProduct]?) -> Void
    @objc func requestProducts(_ ch:ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
        let products : [SKProduct]? = // whatever
        ch(true, products)
    }
}
```

Over on the Objective-C side, your class's *.m* file must import the implicitly generated bridging header:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h" // or whatever it is called
```

In the eyes of your Objective-C class, an IAPBridge has this method:

```
- (void)requestProducts:(SWIFT_NOESCAPE void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSArray<SKProduct *> * _Nullable))ch;
```

So now you just call it:

```
IAPBridge* b = [[IAPBridge alloc] init];
[b requestProducts:^(BOOL success, NSArray<SKProduct *> * products) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Thank you for the products! They are %@", products);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Darn, something went wrong");
    }
}];
```